# Why is there no space between #define and the maro name?

Tags: c

I came across a source file where a space is obviously missing in a macro definition:

There is no space `#define` and `__MIDL_user_allocate_free_DEFINED__`.

```
#ifndef __MIDL_user_allocate_free_DEFINED__
#define__MIDL_user_allocate_free_DEFINED__
  void *__RPC_API MIDL_user_allocate(size_t);
  void __RPC_API MIDL_user_free(void *);
#endif
```

Can someone tell my why?

[Link to code](https://github.com/mrkearden/elmer_mpi_win/blob/0cd3ff84a303507cfc9e2c806bb468f44128262e/stripped_gfortran/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/xmltrnsf.h#L57)

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It looks like a typo to me. It should definitely be `#define __MIDL_user_allocate_free_DEFINED__`. Without the space the could does not compile if the macro `__MIDL_user_allocate_free_DEFINED__` is not defined beforehand.

Comment: @BigCat the code probably compiles fine because `__MIDL_user_allocate_free_DEFINED__` is already defined and therefore the offending macro definition is never seen by the preprocessor